# Matplotlib: Replace a subplot with an existing axes object

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am working with a package that produces only a `matplotlib.Axes` object, but it produces exactly what I want for that particular figure.

It would be highly advantageous, however, to take that object and place it directly into a larger array of existing subplots.  Something like the following:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2)
ax[0,0].plot(...stuff...)
ax[0,1].plot(...stuff...)
ax[1,0].plot(...stuff...)

foo = plot_likert.plot_likert(...stuff...);  # <----- returns Axes object

ax[1,1] = foo  # <----- transplant Axes object
fig.show(()
```

Obviously, it's not that simple. What happens (in jupyter, anyway) is that `ax[1,1]` shows up blank, and `foo` shows up as its own entity, nicely formatted.

Is there a way to do what I'm looking for?

Comment: Consider posting a request on their github issue tracker to accept an `ax` parameter, so then `plot_likert(..., ax=ax[1,1])` would plot directly onto `ax[1,1]`. That's the standard way for high-level APIs (pandas, seaborn) to interact with subplots.

Comment: @tdy Hah-- I just put a request for a different feature a few minutes ago, thinking this was just my ignorance and could be solved at stack.  I may have to add this one, too.

Comment: Are you talking about [this library](https://github.com/nmalkin/plot-likert)?  I think this should be specified in the question - I have never seen that library before.

Comment: It turns out there actually is `ax` support in the pre-release: `pip install --upgrade --pre plot-likert`

Comment: So with the pre-release (0.4.0.dev202202041), we can do: `plot_likert.plot_likert(data, plot_likert.scales.agree, ax=ax[1, 1])` https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6SbN.png